# product of all F_p, p prime

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, nt.number-theory, characteristic-p, ultrafilters

Let $R$ be the ring $$R = \prod_{p\ \text{prime}} \mathbb{F}_p$$ where $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the field having $p$ elements.

Is it true that $R$ has a quotient by a maximal ideal which is a field of characteristic zero and contains $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Motivation: I like the problem and I can't solve it...

It should have something to do with the Chebotarev density theorem.

Comment: There is a proof that avoids the Chebotarev Density Theorem, the missing piece is in Bjorn Poonen's answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15220/is-there-an-elementary-proof-of-the-infinitude-of-completely-split-primes/15221#15221

Comment: The funny thing is: I have been looking at the classical paper "Diophantine problems over local fields" (Ax & Kochen) during the past few days, and in fact the answer to my question is really in this paper.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090780

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is Yes, and this is the [ultraproduct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) construction. Let U be any nonprincipal ultrafilter on the set of primes. This is simply the dual filter to a maximal ideal on the set of primes, containing all finite sets of primes. (In other words, U contains the Frechet filter.)

The quotient R/U is a field of characteristic 0.

The ultraproduct construction is completely general, and has nothing to do with rings or fields. If M<sub>i</sub> for i in I is any collection of first order structures, and U is an ultrafilter on the subsets of I, then we may form the ultraproduct Π M<sub>i</sub>/U, which is the set of equivalence classes by the relation f equiv g iff { i in I | f(i) = g(i) } in U. Similarly, the structure is imposed on the ultraproduct coordinate-wise, and this is well-defined. The most important theorem is Los's theorem, which says that Π M<sub>i</sub>/U satisfies a first order statement phi([f]) if and only if { i in I | M<sub>i</sub> satisfies phi(f(i)) } in U.

In your case, since every F<sub>p</sub> is a field, the ultraproduct is also a field. And since the set of p bigger than any fixed n is in U, then the ultraproduct will have 1+...+1 (n times) not equal to 0, for any fixed n > 0. That is, the ultraproduct will have characteristic 0.

---

Edit: I confess I missed the part initially about containing the algebraic numbers, and so there is more to be done, as Kevin points out. What Los's theorem gives you is that something will be true in R/U just in case the set of p for which F_p has the property is in the ultrafilter U.

What you need to know is that for any finite list of equations, that there is an infinite set of primes p for which the equations have a solution in F<sub>p</sub>. This property is equivalent to asking whether every finite list of equations over Z is true in at least one F<sub>p</sub>, since one can always add one more equation so as to exclude any particular F<sub>p</sub>. Is this true? (I wasn't sure.)

But according to what Kevin says in the comments below, it is true, and this is precisely what you need for the construction to go through. You can form a filter containing those sets, which would form a descending sequence of subsets of primes, and then extend this to an ultrafilter. In this case, any particular equation would have a solution in F<sub>p</sub> for a set of p in U, and so the ultrapower R/U would have a solution. In this case, the ultrapower will contain the algebraic numbers.

Comment: Interesting. I must confess that I do not know the techniques you are using. I "met" the problem in the context of Chebotarev's density theorem...

Comment: This is a method that comes from logic. Ultraproducts and ultrapowers appear all over model theory and set theory. Many large cardinal axioms are stated in terms of various ultrapower of the universe.

Comment: Joel: I read the question as "...and contains an algebraic closure of Q". Am I right in thinking that you read it some other way?

Comment: PS Joel: if I'm right and he did want Q-bar in, can you glance over my answer and instantly tell me exactly what statements about number fields one needs to finish the job?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean, it should contain all algebraic numbers! 

Comment: @AS: then Joel's answer hasn't done the job yet---all he has done is constructed a quotient that has characteristic zero.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am currently trying to understand all this ultra-stuff :p

Comment: I do the ultra-stuff in quite a concrete way in my answer, if that helps any...

Comment: @Joel: here are some statements you might need to finish the job. (1) a field of char 0 contains Q-bar iff every monic polynomial with integer coefficients factors into linear factors in the field. (2) if f is a monic poly with Z coeffts and S(f) is the set of primes p for which f factors completely mod p then S(f) is infinite (and indeed has positive density---this is Cebotarev, or at least a consequence, and is non-formal). (3) Any finite intersection of the S(f)'s is also infinite (because S(f) cap S(g)=S(fg)). (4) For any p there's an f with p not in S(f). Is that enough for you?

Comment: All you need is that the statements that you want to be true in R/U are true in most F_p. Then they will be true in the ultrapower. 

Comment: @Mr Buzzard: it does help, but still, I need some time for all this... :) It doesn't look like there will be a method for this problem which doesn't use this kind of constructions from logic?

Comment: If you have countably many things to say, and the set of p for which they are true give rise to a descending sequence of infinite sets, then these sets all lie in a nonprincipal filter, which can be extended to an ultrafilter. So you'll get it in M/U. 

Comment: You have countably many things to say: you alternate between saying statements of the form "this prime isn't 0" and "this monic polynomial with integer coefficients factors into linear factors". For any finite initial sequence of this countably infinite list of statements, the set of primes satisfying all of them is infinite (but this is a non-trivial fact). So if I've understood you correctly, we're home!

Comment: Ok, I think I sort of get what happens - it is my first encounter with ultraproducts :) so I shouldn't feel bad about not being able to solve the problem, I guess. I like the problem very much, and I guess using ultraproducts is really the right way (and the only way) to do it.

Comment: Ultraproducts are great, and I highly recommend them. You can form the ultraproducts of any type of structure---groups, rings, graphs, partial orders, whatever, and Los says that in every case, truth in the ultraproduct is the same as truth on a large set of coordinates, for any first order statement.

Comment: And Thanks, Kevin, for supplying Cebotarev's theroem, which is critical for this application!

Comment: But now I wonder: is it conceivable that we can actually make the ultraproduct algebraically closed? For this, one would need to know whether for each n, there are infinitely many primes p such that polynomials over F_p of degree n have zeros in F_p. Is this true? If so, we could choose the filter to make R/U algebraically closed.

Comment: @Joel: No. Every F_p has an irreducible quadratic, hence so does the ultrapower.

Comment: Thanks, Francois. At http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_algebraically_closed_field, it is stated at least that every nonprincipal ultraproduct of distinct finite fields is *pseudo algebraically closed*, as a consequence of the Riemann Hypothesis for function fields.

Answer (score 9):

How far does the logic route get you? Here's a plan of attack. Say we have such a max ideal $m$.

1) If $S$ is a subset of the primes then there's an idempotent $e_S$ in $R$, which is 1 at $p$ if $p\in S$ and $0$ at $p$ otherwise. Now $e_S$ is an idempotent so either $e_S\in m$ or $e_S-1\in m$. Say $S$ is "big" if $e_S-1\in m$ and "small" if $e_S\in m$. I suspect that

(@) a set is big iff its complement is small (easy).

(a) $m$ is determined by the collection of $S$ such that $S$ is big

(b) the big $S$ form an ultrafilter

(c) This gives you a bijection between ultrafilters on the set of primes and maximal ideals.

The principal ultrafilters are the ones corresponding to the obvious quotients $R\to\mathbf{F}_p$. Any non-principal ultrafilter will give a quotient of $R$ of characteristic zero.

I don't know if (1) is right but I've always suspected it is. If it's true the proof will be straightforward algebra.

2) Now use the logicians point of view. A 1st order statement of field theory is true in $R/m$ iff the set of primes for which it's true in $\mathbf{F}_p$ is big. For example the statement "I am a field with a square root of 2" is true for a set of primes of density 1/2 (those which are 1 or 7 mod 8), so this set had better be big if you want the quotient to have a square root of 2.

3) Now enumerate all polynomials with integer coefficients and say "I have all my roots in $R/m$". All these sets had better be big. So now we have some sort of combinatorial question, which I think is the following. Let $K$ run through all number fields, Galois over $\mathbf{Q}$ for simplicity, and for each one let $S(K)$ denote the set of primes that split completely in $K$. Is there an ultrafilter which contains all of these $S(K)$?

4) Now a bunch of sets is contained in an ultrafilter iff it generates a filter that isn't the whole set of primes. But now this is some combinatorial statement about primes splitting completely in number fields. For example, statements of the form "if $S$ is the primes that split completely in $K$ and $T$ is the set of primes that split completely in $L$, then $S\cap T$ is the set of primes that split completely in $KL$" will be of use to you here. In fact is that all you need?? Figure this out and you're home.

It's time for bed here in the UK (well, at least if you have 3 kids it is) but I'd be interested to know what happens if you try and push this through.

Comment: Joel's answer basically says "you only need one direction of (1): ultrafilters give you max ideals". The comments below his answer justify that the primes that split completely do indeed extend to a non-principal ultrafilter. So the result is true!

Answer (score 9):

Combining the answers of Joel and Kevin does work.

Write $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty K_n$ where the $K_n$ are an increasing sequence of finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $S_n$ be the primes that split completely in $K_n$. By [Chebotarev's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem), this is a descending sequence of infinite sets of primes. Therefore, there is a nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ over the set of primes which contains all $S_n$. If $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ has a root in $K_n$, then $f(x)$ has roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for all $p \in S_n$ and hence $f(x)$ has a root in the ultraproduct $\prod_p \mathbb{F}_p/\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: Sorry for the duplication, I hadn't read the long thread of comments where this is all explained.

Comment: It's actually only a weak consequence of Cebotarev's theorem, and can be obtained in a more elementary manner. You just need that the zeta function of the number field has a pole, which is a basic fact. This is one of those algebraic-looking results whose most natural proofs are analytic.

Comment: Very interesting point, Kevin. Is there a proof of the infinitude of completely splitting primes that doesn't involve analysis? (I vaguely remember seeing such a thing in the Abelian case.)

Comment: There is a very simple elementary proof of the infinitude of completely split primes! http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15220/is-there-an-elementary-proof-of-the-infinitude-of-completely-split-primes