# How constructive is Dirichlet on primes in progressions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a known elementary function bound in terms of $a,b,n$ for the $n$-th prime equal to $b$ modulo $a$ (coprime to $b$)?

Bounds on Linnik's constant answer this for the first prime in each progression.  Is there a known analogue for an $n$-th prime in a progression?  And I found some references on an error term for the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions.  But I don't see how to turn these into a construction for arbitrary $a,b,n$.

Comment: One "construction" is simply to check all the numbers to see if they're prime. Is there even a better way to find the $n$th prime among all the primes?

Comment: The error term should give an explicit $x_0$ and an explicit positive constant $C \lt 1/\varphi(a)$ such that $|\{p \leq x : p \equiv b \pmod{a}\}| \geq Cx/\log x$ for all $x \geq x_0$. Then the first $x \geq x_0$ such that $Cx/\log x \geq n$ gives an upper bound on the $n$-th prime $b \pmod{a}$.

Comment: Actually Will Sawin's comment is incorrect, though it led to improving the question.  Brute force will find the $n$-th prime only if there is one! In other words, it is not a constructive technique unless you can bound how long the search needs to be.  It seems you can bound it.

Comment: @François G. Dorais: The versions of Dirichlet's theorem before Linnik's theorem did not give an explicit $C$, because the $C$ furnished by the proof depended on a possible Siegel zero for the modulus $a$. See also my response below.

Comment: The case of primes $1 \pmod{n}$ is provable (with a much worse bound) in PA using the argument from http://mathoverflow.net/a/15221/2000

Comment: ... and this paper by KConrad - http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf - shows that the same trick works for primes $a \pmod{n}$ when $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ (and in no other cases).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corollary 18.8 in Iwaniec-Kowalski's Analytic number theory shows the existence of an explicitly computable $L>3/2$ such that for $x>a^L$ and $(a,b)=1$, the number of primes less than $x$ and congruent to $b$ modulo $a$ is at least a constant times $\frac{x}{\varphi(a)\sqrt{a}\log x}$. So the $n$-th prime congruent to $b$ modulo $a$ is less than a constant times $a^L n\log (2n)$.

Comment: I doubt you can find a constant multiple of $x$; surely it's $x/\log(x)$?

Comment: @Carl: You are right, I had the Chebyshev function $\psi(x,a,b)$ in mind rather than the prime counting function $\pi(x,a,b)$. I updated my response accordingly.