# Is there an elementary proof that there are infinitely many primes that are *not* completely split in an abelian extension?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, number-fields, elementary-proofs

I'm currently in the middle of teaching the adelic algebraic proofs of global class field theory.  One of the intermediate lemmas that one shows is the following:

**Lemma:** if L/K is an abelian extension of number fields, then there are infinitely many primes of K that do not split competely in L.

Of course this is implied by Cebotarev's density theorem, but the adelic proof uses only algebra/topology and finiteness of class number/Dirichlet's units theorem.

There is a well-known elementary proof, [(see eg this MO question)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15220/is-there-an-elementary-proof-of-the-infinitude-of-completely-split-primes) that there are infinitely many primes that *are*  split in L/K.  I was wondering whether there is also an elementary argument for infinitude of non-split primes in the extension?  (As usual the notion of "elementary" is flexible, but I'm looking for something that uses a minimum of machinery.)

One possibility would be to distill the adelic proof into something algebraic, although this seems hard.  Another option would be to look for ideals of O_K that are not norms from O_L: any such ideal must have a factor which does not split completely.

One of the answers to the MathOverflow question linked above does mention the paper *Primes of degree one and algebraic cases of Čebotarev's theorem* of Lenstra and Stevenhagen, which gives an elementary proof under the assumption that L contains a nontrivial ray class field of K.  But it seems that one still needs to prove the first inequality in some form to use this.

Comment: If $K=\mathbb{Q}$ this follows from Kronecker-Weber. Suppose $L\subset\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ corresponds to a proper subgroup $H\leq (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$. A rational prime $p\nmid n$ splits completely in $L$ iff $p\mod n$ is in $H$. If $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ are primes not dividing $n$ that do not split completely, we can pick $r\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times\backslash H$ and use the CRT to find a positive integer $Q$ congruent to $1$ mod $p_1\cdots p_m$ and congruent to $r$ mod $n$. Then $Q$ must have a prime divisor that does not split completely, which is not $p_1,\ldots,p_m$.

Comment: @JulianRosen Yes, and I believe that's the argument that Lenstra and Stevenhagen generalize to arbitrary ray class fields.

Answer (score 17):

I mention this as an answer since it is too long for comments. I do not know what the adelic proof assumes. Suppose that all but finitely many primes of $K$ split completely in $L$. Suppose $d$ is the degree of $L$ over $K$.  Then the zeta function of $L$ is the $d$-th power of the zeta function of $K$, up to finitely many factors. But the Zeta functions of $L$ and $K$ have only a simple pole at $s=1$ (implied by finiteness of class number ...). Hence $d=1$ and $L=K$.

Comment: Good point!  That's certainly simpler than the adelic proof.